# Ehcache write-behind caching thread-priority

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I'm trying to use Ehcache write-behind caching to write batches of transactions to my database. What I need is for the write-behind cache to dump transactions at 5 second intervals (or more often).

I must be missing something, because try as I might, it just won't work. I set up the write-behind caching, and then put load onto the server. Thousands, and then hundreds of thousands of transactions later, and after waiting several minutes, there is still nothing in the database. It isn't until I shut down the load on the server that the cache begins writing to the database.

Is this a problem with thread-priority? Is there a way to modify the Ehcache to perform the DB writes even when the server is under load?

Here is my configuration:

```
<cache name="server.db.model.Request"
 maxElementsInMemory="10000"
 eternal="false"
 timeToIdleSeconds="5"
 timeToLiveSeconds="5"
 overflowToDisk="false"
 memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO">
    <cacheWriter writeMode="write_behind" maxWriteDelay="5" rateLimitPerSecond="5"
     writeCoalescing="true" writeBatching="true" writeBatchSize="5000"
     retryAttempts="2" retryAttemptDelaySeconds="10">
        <cacheWriterFactory class="server.db.util.RequestCacheWriterFactory"/> 
    </cacheWriter>
</cache>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, changing my configuration to this is what worked - though I'm still not sure which parameter change made the difference.

```
<cache name="server.db.model.Request"
  maxElementsInMemory="10000" 
  maxElementsOnDisk="0"
  eternal="false"
  timeToIdleSeconds="5"
  timeToLiveSeconds="5">
      <cacheWriter writeMode="write_behind" maxWriteDelay="5" 
        writeCoalescing="false" writeBatching="true" writeBatchSize="5000"
        retryAttempts="2" retryAttemptDelaySeconds="10"
        notifyListenersOnException="false" writeBehindMaxQueueSize="10000" 
        writeBehindConcurrency="10" >
         <cacheWriterFactory class="server.db.util.RequestCacheWriterFactory" />
      </cacheWriter>
</cache>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... that's really weird. We have been doing extensive testing and have never experienced the writer thread never getting CPU time. What OS are you running ? Is the thread creating the CacheManager running at a lower priority ?

Also, sorry for maybe asking the obvious, but when you say "shut down" the load what does that mean ? Not shutting the app (and the CacheManager) down ? Basically what I am asking is "Transaction demarcation does happen within the writeAll/deleteAll method, right ?"…

One last remark as well, as this is tagged with hibernate, you didn't configure write-behind on a hibernate 2nd level cache right ? That's just a wrong tag, isn't it ?

Comment: This is on a Linux/Tomcat environment. We haven't explicitly set thread-priority anywhere. By shutting down the load, I mean that I shutdown the jMeter threads that I'm using to hit the server. And, lastly, we are using hibernate, according to the ehcache documentation here: http://ehcache.org/documentation/hibernate.html. Oddly enough, even after I shut down the load on the server, I have to wait another 5 minutes or so before the writes to the database begin happening. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm confused, so server.db.model.Request holds hibernate data ? I mean you are aware that you shouldn't use ehcache write-behind with hibernate caches, right ? Also, what version are you using ? Also that is ehcache standalone right ? Not Terracotta clustered …